# Opening an Email from a network folder and Replying to that email

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have code that works well to open an email from a folder, extract the excel sheet from the email and save it to the same folder, close the message. What I want to do is to reply to that email with some specific wording. I have the below code but it is not working. I know its the "From" email address but i can't figure out where my error is. I am sure that it is something simple but i just don't know enough to fix it. I have looked at many topics here but just can't seem to crack the code. Please help me

```
    Set Outapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    Set outEmail = Outapp.Session.OpenSharedItem(PORFQFolder & Filename)
    
    For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
        If outAttachment.Filename Like "*.xls*" Then
        POUploadFile1 = PORFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename
        outAttachment.SaveAsFile PORFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename
        QuoteFile = "Y"
        End If
    Next
    With outEmail
    .ReplyAll
    .to = .SenderEmailAddress
    .HTMLbody = "Your quote has been received and processed."
    .display
    .send
    End With
```

Comment: Exactly what is issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? I don't see any code that involves From address. Did you mean issue is with To address? I have never tried ReplyAll but woudn't that conflict with To? Should `.to` be `.from`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ReplyAll` line actually create a new email whereas you are continuing to work with the received email ... replace your `With` block with this:

```
With outEmail.ReplyAll
    .To = outEmail.SenderEmailAddress
    .HTMLBody = "Your quote has been received and processed."
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. I knew it was something simple

Comment: Great, if you have a moment can you accept my answer (click on the grey check mark)?